# Somehow accessing Javascript output?

Tags: php, javascript

So,

Say there's a remote PHP file that's generating some output in JavaScript.
I can do `<script src='some_file.php type='text/javascript'></script>`, and the code will run, but when I click View Source it just shows the above code.  Is there any way I can access the actual code that that PHP file is running?

Also, when I right click on the output of the javascript and go to 'this frame' -> 'view frame source' I get the actual output.  I want to be able to use it.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What exactly do you want?

Comment: If that was possible, every website using PHP will be **DOOMED**.

Comment: It's for an advertising script.  It's a php script with a bunch of shit in it, loaded via javascript. the script shows links to advertisements.  i want to be able to access those links w/o clicking on them.

Comment: i.e. http://rs-downfall.com/scripts/src.htm

Comment: I don't understand: the second-last sentence in your question says "I get the actual output", so haven't you already got what you want?

Comment: Nope.  do what I said if you're using firefox, and you'll see what i mean.  I can view it, but i want to actually have access to it with a script I'm writing.  The links shown change depending on what advertisement is showing.. etc..

Answer (score 5):

This is inherently impossible.

PHP runs on the server; the browser is never aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, PHP runs on the server and generates a html code as shown in your browser.
Do you want it to show?

Comment: What I want is to be able to use preg_match_all on it to get a collection of the content.  It's a javascript that displays links, when you mouse over the image with the links you get the actual URL, but if you view the source, you just get `<script src=..` etc